Moving file with date using Unix command
I want to move all .XML files in the current working directory whose name starts with DAPRETAIL followed by the current date in YYYYMMDD format to a separate directory.
I tried:
DATE='date +%Y%m%d'
mv DAPRETAIL${DATE}*.XML /some/destination

But it returns a: mv: cannot stat 'date +%Y%m%d' error.

I don't want to change file name just move the file name using date in file name

Use date=$(...) in place of DATE='...' and "$date" in place of ${DATE}.

Examples? What system are you running this on (not putty, but the system itself)

It can't return the stated error with the code example you've provided

dt=$(date +%Y%m%d)

mv DAPRETAIL$dt*.XML destination_folder_path


I suspect (but I don't know) that the downvote for your code is because you haven't explained what's going on

I would further suggest, looking at your answer history, that your series of negative scores is at least partly due to the lack of explanations generally. Code solves the problem, sure, but doesn't necessarily teach the person asking the question how to apply your answer in a different situation
